# What does the ratio of angle over position in a sine wave represent?

Tags: waves

[image: ratio of angle over position is equal to ratio of 2pi over wavelength]

I do not understand why the first ratio is equal to the second ratio shown in the diagram. It is very odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming x is the spatial coordinate of the line that the wave is traveling along which has units of distance.

The numerator of both is in radians and the denominator of both is units of distance. So it is dimensionally consistent: radians / distance.

LHS is number of cycles in radians required to travel a unit longitudinal distance. RHS is the number of radians required to travel one wavelength.

Identical in meaning once you simplify the fraction.

Comment: isnt W just the number of radians in a second, not number of cycles in one wavelength?

Comment: Oh wait I made a mix up. I read $\lambda$ as $t$ in some cases but not in others. It's not $\omega$.

Comment: x is the position of the wave at a certain time t, in x metres away from the equilibrium

Comment: @WinnieThePooh  Realize that what you mean when you say "equilibrium" is unclear here.

Comment: okay. x should be "the distance in metres that the wave travels "

Comment: We're on the same page then.

Comment: displacement is the word.

Comment: what is 2pi radians exactly? distance?

Comment: GO to chat.........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131836/discussion-between-dknguyen-and-winniethepooh).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the $\sin\theta$ function is periodic, and that it repeats itself on every $\theta + 2\pi$. So one "cycle" has the "width" of $2\pi$ in the graph. While $\theta$ is usually some sort of an angle, it doesn't have to be - think of it just as of a number, a mathematical parameter to the $\sin$ function. Imagine having some UI with a slider that lets you provide input, and as you move the slider, the function happens to repeat itself once you go past the $2\pi$ mark. It's just a number, doesn't have to mean anything physical.

The quantity $2\pi/\lambda$ is something called "the wavenumber"; it represents the number of radians per unit distance, but a better way to think about it is that it tells you how many cycles "fit" into a span of $2\pi$ on the horizontal axis. So, if you take the "standard" sine wave, and reduce the wavelength by half ($2\pi \to \pi$), you can fit 2 cycles into the $2\pi$ range ($2\pi/\lambda = 2\pi/\pi = 2)$. If you double the wavelength ($2\pi \to 4\pi$), then you can only fit half a cycle ($2\pi/\lambda = 2\pi/4\pi = 1/2)$. The wavenumber is typically denoted with $k$.

[image]
([image source](https://yoshiwarabooks.org/trig/The-General-Sinusoidal-Function.html))

> I do not understand why the first ratio is equal to the second ratio shown in the diagram.

This isn't really shown in the diagram; the image only shows the "standard" sinusoid, that is, the function $\sin\theta$. Now remember, purely mathematically, it doesn't matter what $\theta$ is - it's just a parameter. So, if you have a string and you're making a wave with it in space (or if you take a marker and draw a wave on a whiteboard), if you set things up just right, you can arrange that your string/drawing takes the exactly the shape described by $\sin x$, so that the cycle repeats after the distance of $2\pi$ meters. That is, you can make it so that the mathematical value of the parameter to the "standard" sinusoid corresponds to the actual distance $x$ you can measure in space.

But generally, that's not going to be the case; typically, you'll make some arbitrary wave, and it will be a scaled version compared to the "standard" one. E.g. it might have a spatial period of only 0.1 m.

So, thinking again of $\theta$ not as of an angle, but as of as of a generic parameter to the mathematical $\sin\theta$ function, what you want to determine is how you can tweak the input to $\sin\theta$ so that it reproduces the correct shape for your string/drawing, when given, as input, a measurement of the length along the axis of your wave. In other words, you want $\theta = f(x)$ to be some function of $x$; you want to find that function, and then do $\sin (f(x))$.

Now, since all we're doing here is scaling, this $\theta$ that we are looking for is proportional to $x$. It's just $x$ times some scaling factor, so: $\theta = kx$. Now, what else do we know? Well, you can measure the spatial period. E.g., you take out a ruler and you determine that cycles along your string/drawing repeat every $\lambda = 0.1$ m. Great; that means that when $x$ is $0.1$ m, $\theta$ should be $2\pi$. Since $\theta$ is proportional to $x$ ($\theta$ is a linear map of $x$), all you need to do now is make a proportion; $\theta$ compared to some arbitrary $x$ must be the same as $2\pi$ compared to $\lambda$:

[image]

$$\frac{\theta}{x} = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} \\
\theta = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} x \\
\theta = kx; \space k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$

So now you can use $\sin (kx)$ to describe your string/drawing - except that the amplitude might be scaled as well, and since the output of $\sin (kx)$ oscillates between -1 and 1, all you need to do is multiply it by the measured amplitude: $y = A\sin(kx)$

[image]
([image source](https://yoshiwarabooks.org/trig/The-General-Sinusoidal-Function.html))